# QGIS not saving shapes

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am using QGIS 2.18.7 on my laptop.  I can add a new shapelayer, but when I stop editing, the shapes that I have entered disappear.  I have tried point, line and polygon shapes, they all appear to allow creation of points/line/polygons, but when I stop editing, it all disappears.

On my desktop machine it works correctly.

Is this a configuration or installation issue?

Comment: Sounds like a windows permissions issue or read-only shapefile.

Comment: Try uninstall QGIS from your laptop and reinstall it again. Please note that sometimes the antivirus software may block some files during installation. You may need to disable the antivirus temporarily when installing QGIS. But make it last choice. First try to reinstall normally, and if it failed, then disable antivirus and reinstall again.